# How to open barcode scanner in a custom widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, barcode-scanner, flutter-widget

I want to open barcode scanner in a container - Custom Widget (Not just barcode scanner QR). For example, while scanning the barcode at the top of the screen, I want to put a button at the bottom to add the barcode I scanned to the shopping cart. Can you suggest a library or method to do this?

I am putting an example picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Stack` widget to achieve this (to overlap one widget on another).
I used *qr_code_scanner* plugin in my case.

```
Stack(
    children:[
        /* replace this widget with your own */
        QRView(
            key: qrKey,
            onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
        ),
        Column(
            children:[
                /* button control here */
            ]
        ),
    ]
);
```

See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html for more info about stack.

Comment: This answer seems correct. When I started the project, I did not see this library and used another one. I will probably move the scan to this library. Thank you so much.